# Ruby on Rails: Use Variable in link_to helper path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I've got a HAML partial that receives a variable `bar`, and I'd like to inject that variable in the link_to path.

For example:

```
= link_to new_foo_path, class: 'source card' do
    .stuff
```

I want to replace foo with bar.

I've tried:

```
= link_to new_#{bar}_path, class: 'source card' do
```

and a dozen other things, but nothing seems to work.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try it like this:

`link_to send("new_#{bar}_path"), class: "source card" do`

Basically, send makes something a method or variable, and it allows you to combine everything in that string into one variable.

Comment: and how would you pass a parameter in that?

Comment: figured out another way.

Comment: to pass parameters to send, just add a comma "," after the string `"new_#{bar}_path"` and add a hash of parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can add parameters to the link helper like this:

```
link_to "New Foo", new_foo_path(bar: "bar")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `eval`:

```
= link_to eval("new_#{bar}_path"), class: 'source card' do
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar situation so I created a view helper. For your case I guess you can do something similar.

Create a view helper function inside `helpers/application_helper.rb`:

```
def custom_path pathvar
   if pathvar == 'foo'
      new_foo_path
   elsif pathvar == 'bar'
      new_bar_path
   end
end
```

Then in your view, you can use it like this:

```
= link_to custom_path(bar), class: 'source card' do
```

You can modify the example as per your needs. This looks more elegant to me.